# How can I provide a limited output of a PHP-Loop from a SoapClient call to 19 items?

Tags: php, soap

I make a SOAP call and return a tree-object with the data I want to process. I use a foreach() loop and I display it on a page. However some of the calls got too many items and I need to add a limit to the iteration to a X ammount of items on the front end.

```
foreach($variable->node->node as $object) { ?>
  <div class="page"><p><? echo $object->node; ?></p></div>
```

With this limit I wonder how can I can I do something like a counter to 19 items before adding a break and a close  tab. so it end ups like:

```
<div class="page"><p>item 1</p><p>item 2</p>.... item 20</p></div>
 <div class="page"><p>item 20</p><p>item 21</p>....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a counter in two ways, first a regular counter like:

```
$counter++;
```

That code increments var $counter by one. Or you can use this statement for the counter:

```
foreach($variable->node->node as $counter=>$object) {
```

With this done, you can now create the point of break with this:

```
if(!($counter % 19)) add_break_and_close_tab()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk). Allowing you to chunk your array into items of 19 so that you can print effectively.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 19);

<?php foreach($chunks as $group) : ?>
    <div class="page">

        <?php foreach($group as $item) : ?>

            <p><?php echo $item; ?></p>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#SZvMbX9Yc)

---

<sup>*The above would print your data out exactly how you want it. Never going over the chunk limit (`19` in this case)*</sup>